# Deque appending dictionary vs Deque(dictionary) in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, deque

Try to get my head around adding `dictionary` to a `deque` .

Take this example:

```
from collections import deque
graph={}
graph['key']=['value_1','value_2','value_3']
implement_first=deque()
implement_second=deque(graph['key'])
implement_first.append(graph['key'])
```

and If I print:

```
    print(implement_first)
    print(implement_first.popleft())
```

I get this `deque([['value_1', 'value_2', 'value_3']])` and
`['value_1', 'value_2', 'value_3']`

and If I print:

```
print(implement_second)
print(implement_second.popleft())
```

I get this :
`deque(['value_1', 'value_2', 'value_3'])` and `value_1`

So what is going on here ? why am I getting list of list for `implement_first.append(graph['key'])` and what is this implementation `implement_second=deque(graph['key'])` does?

Comment: `deque(graph['key'])` initialized the deque with 3 elements whereas `implement_first.append(graph['key'])` appends whole list as first element of the deque.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following 2 are not equivalent

```
d1 = deque(x)

d2 = deque()
d2.append(x)
```

The `deque` constructor takes an iterable and appends all its elements. So the following 2 would be the same

```
d1 = deque(x)

d2 = deque()
for y in x:
    d2.append(y)
```

Yours does not raise any errors because `graph["key"]` is a list (an iterable) which can be both *turned into* a `deque` and *be an element of* a `deque`.